# Creating shorter link for image folder

Tags: php, laravel

I created new disks for images in my project, and I want to use URL that I added to userImage disk in my view in blade.php.

The disk works perfect in my controller, I use it to detect if the folder path exists, if not I am creating one:

```php
if (!Storage::disk('userImage')->has('standard')) {
     Storage::disk('userImage')->makeDirectory('standard');
}
```

But I want to use it also in my blade.php pageview, right now I am using:

(C:\xampp\htdocs\rps\public\storage\images\userImage\standard\default.png)

```
src="{{asset('storage/images/userImage/standard/default.png')}}"
```

The code above works perfectly, it displays the image but I want to shorten it to:

```
src="{{asset('userImage/standard/default.png')}}"
```

and I hoped it will work by how my userImage disk works but it doesn't. Anyone has an idea of how to solve this issue?

```php
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'userImage' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/images/userImage'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/userImage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: Please refer Laravel Filesystem https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

**If you want shorter img url:**

You can make symbol link from `public/userImage` to `storage/app/public/images/userImage`.

1. Add to your console.php in routes folder.

   ```
   Artisan::command('link', function(){
       $this->laravel->make('files')->link(
           storage_path('app/public/images/userImage'), public_path('userImage')
       );
   });
   ```
2. And then console command:

   ```
   php artisan link
   ```

**If you want shorter code (path in blade):**

You can create your own helper function.

1. Create file app/Helpers/helpers.php

   ```
   function image($path){
       $path = trim($path, '/');
       return asset('storage/images/' . $path);
   }
   ```
2. Add it to composer's autoload

   ```
   "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
       ],
       "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
       },
       "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
       ]
   },
   ```
3. Use it in blade:

   ```
   {{ image('userImage/standard/default.png') }}
   ```

Comment: I see how it works but when I call that function in a blade I get: `Call to undefined function image()` Do I need to refresh my composer or something to make it work? `composer update` didn't help me @IndianCoding